# Scrolling sticks/jumps for a second halfway down website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When I scroll down on my site, it always sticks/jumps right at the halfway point. I'm not sure what is causing this.

I've tried changing "height" to "min-height"(I heard that works)
I honestly don't know whats causing this co I haven't tried much.

I'm not sure what to post but this is the code corresponding to the the area of the site where the scrolling sticks.

```css
.tools {
    background: url('../img/tools.png') no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    min-height: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 800%;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}

.toolsinfo {
    background: url('../img/tools.png') no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    font-size: 150%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 50px 80px;
    background-color: #323232;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}

#bar {
    min-height: 30px;
    background: url('../img/bar1.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</section>

<div id="paralax2" class="tools">
    <h2 style="font-size:25%; padding-top:50px; color: black">Skills and Tech</h2>

    <div id="" class="toolsinfo">
        <div class="icons" style="padding-top:100px;">
            <div class="icon" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="icon" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="icon" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="icon" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="icon" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.pngg" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="icons" style="padding-bottom:100px;">
            <div class="icon" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="icon" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="icon" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="icon" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                <a class="link" href="#">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bar2">
        <section>
            <div id="bar"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be a case where a video is needed. Do you have a parallax script running? Also is it happening on all browsers or just Chrome/Firefox/IE?

Comment: Ive only seen it happen in chrome fro some reason. IE, and Firefox run fine.

Comment: Try going to `chrome://flags` in your browser and enabling smooth scroll.